# How can I identify what application is using a given file on a network shared drive on windows?

Tags: windows, file

I know that process explorer or handle can be used to find out on a machine what files are opened.  But what if the file is on a network drive where many machines can have access to the file, then is there a way to tell what are all the machines that have access to the file without checking on each machine's process explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it on the server that the networkdrive belongs to. It depends on the operating system. e.g. On Windows server 2008 R2 you can do it with Openfiles:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490961.aspx

Openfiles.exe /query /s SERVERNAME

In Windows 7 you can see it at MyComputer Right-Click->Manage->Shared Folder->Open files